# Bind ViewChild to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, viewchild

I am showing the tabular data in DataTable for Angular. Now I have a button to which I am attaching a click event. On the clicking event, I am showing a slide menu, on clicking on it, it is triggering a modal open. I am using `ViewChild` for showing the sliding menu and the method is like the following :

```
openAction() {

        this.renderer.removeClass(this.actionslide.nativeElement, "hidden");

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.actionslide.nativeElement, "height", "15rem");
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.actionslide.nativeElement, "width", "10rem");
            this.renderer.setStyle(
                this.actionslide.nativeElement,
                "padding",
                "0.5rem"
            );
        }, 10);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.actioncontainer.nativeElement, "hidden");
        }, 600);
    }
```

and the HTML is like the following:

```
<div class="action-layout hidden" #actionSlide>
    <div class="action-container hidden animate__animated" #actionContainer>
        //Slider menu goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is working for the single element. My problem is that I am displaying this inside a `ngfor` and so the slidermenu has to be displayed for each of the element when clicking on the button on the row. How ca I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

On your datatable you iterate over an array so you can specify an index like this `*ngFor="let thing of things; index as i"`  that you give to your method `openAction(i)`.

Then you loop to create your slide menus, and on your method, thanks to the index you can specify the slide in `i` position.

Comment: How do  I know the position of the row there?  for each of the table rows, I have the hidden element for the slide row. So how to  change the class of the correct element ?

Comment: You can get an array of elementsByClass with `action-layout` class, so once you got your array you can easily specify which one you want with the index of your method

Comment: can you please add an example ?

Comment: Well, can you provide a stackblitz with a your app as minimal working application so I will directly show you on your app.

Comment: I have done half of this using `renderer` . It is like this `openAction(event) {
        var parent = this.renderer.parentNode(event.target);
        var containerRef = this.renderer.nextSibling(parent);

        this.renderer.removeClass(containerRef, "hidden");`

Comment: Now need to get one child inside the `containerRef`

Comment: Ok, and how do you create you DataTable on your template please ?